# What is the best way to implement Paypal and Stripe in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I'm making an ecommerce website (for a portfolio project) and I was wondering if there were any examples on how to implement both Stripe and Paypal on a single website in Node.js. Unfortunately, I can't find any examples/repos that show both Stripe and Paypal used on the same site. Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am wondering this as well. Having to maintain payment information between two different API's seems a little hacky, but it may be necessary.

I suggest have some backend/server-side helper that will interface and return same data for stripe/paypal depending if a payment method is stripe/paypal ( `boolean` value somewhere )